# Question about the definition of a complex manifold

Tags: complex-analysis, manifolds, complex-manifolds

"If a topological manifold $M$ has even dimension $n=2m$, we can identify $\mathbb{R}^{2m}$ with $\mathbb{C}^m$ and require the transition maps to be complex-analytic; this determines a complex-analytic structure. A manifold endowed with this structure is called a complex manifold."

This is a definition I encountered in John Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds book in p.15. Here, what does it mean by "complex-analytic"? I have to deal with functions from open sets $\mathbb{C}^m$ to open sets of $\mathbb{C}^m$. Thus, the phrase "complex-analytic" would not mean the usual "holomorphic". Could anyone please explain what "complex anayltic" mean?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorphic_function#Several_variables

Comment: Complex-analytic, real-analytic, see for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2667655/restriction-of-complex-analytic-functions-to-real-numbers).

Comment: Complex-analytic is the same as holomorphic, just a different name.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier in the link, the definition is restricted to cases where $f$ is only complex-valued. I want to know the definition in which $f$'s codomain is $\mathbb{C}^n$.

Comment: @MoisheCohen So, how does that extends to general complex vector spaces?

Comment: @Keith: Do you mean finite-dimensional ones? A map $f=(f_1,...,f_m): C^n\to C^m$ (defined on an open subset of $C^n$) is called holomorphic if each component $f_k$ is holomorphic.

Comment: @MoisheCohen So, does "complex-analytic" in my question mean what you just wrote?

Comment: @Keith: Yes, that's right.